# Make an Object parent of another Object

Tags: scripting, unity-game-engine, parent, collision

I have a player with rigid body and a sphere, I am using `OnCollisionEnter` and want to make (player/objectA parent of sphere/objectB), if I use the script (where tag "GameController" is for player and tag "sphere" is for sphere) and attached this script to sphere, sphere becomes parent of player but when I attach this script to player, player would not becomes the parent of sphere. Any one know how to solve this problem?

```
//script when attached to sphere
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {

     Debug.Log ("collision occur");
     if(col.gameObject.tag=="player")
     {
         col.transform.parent=transform;
     }
 }

//script when attached to player
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {

     Debug.Log ("collision occur");
     if(col.gameObject.tag=="sphere")
     {
         col.transform.parent=transform;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Make sure you are getting inside this `if(col.gameObject.tag=="sphere")`

Answer (score 0):

well there is nothing wrong with the code i guess can you make sure you are getting inside the if statement ? and can you double check if the sphere has the tag sphere and that you have spelled it correctly ?

Comment: it's case sensitive, so "Sphere" and "sphere" are different